# Join two different sql tables with columns that have the same data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different sql statements I'm executing and one works and the other one semi works if I remove the ambiguous column. Is there a way to specify which columns I want to grab information from on both tables?

```
select * from currentprojects
     Join Group on Group.projectcode= currentprojects.projectcode
```

This is the first statement and it works but when the table is displayed the whole page breaks.

```
SELECT 
   name,
   projectid,
   projectcode,
   completiondate,
   meeting,
   status
FROM currentprojects
Join Group on Group.status= currentprojects.projectcode
```

The second statement works if I remove projectcode from the query, but I want to have both datasets showing different things.

Comment: is "FROM Projects" in your second query a typo?

Comment: By "works" do you means runs without an error, or runs accomplishing what you want?

Comment: What's the error when it "breaks"?

Comment: yea that was a typo but it run successfully but breaks the webpage.

Comment: there is no error the page runs successfully and just has a bunch of empty data in a lot of rows

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Without some details the best anybody can do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. Aliasing helps once your queries start getting pretty dense

```
 SELECT cp.Cloumn, g.Column 
 FROM currentprojects cp
 INNER JOIN Group g ON g.projectcode= cp.projectcode
```

Comment: See I was trying inner join earlier but I couldn't figure out how to syntax it correctly? I guess that's the word and it works now thank you! ^_^